# Spinner activity getting force closed

Tags: android, spinner

I am using the following code for `spinner1` as the product choice and I have to give the `spinner2` the data depending on `spinner1` content. `spinner2` should display items, but it is getting force closed when I run it. Can anybody share your experience?

```
public class SpinnerActivity extends Activity  {

private String[] spinner1values = new String[] { "Automobiles", "Jobs" };
private String[][] spinner2values = new String[][] {
        new String[] { "a1", "b1", "c1" },
        new String[] { "a2", "b2" }
};
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_spinner);

    Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinner1values);
    adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner1.setAdapter(adapter1);

    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int position, long arg3) {
            // create a new adapter with the corresponding values
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(arg0.getContext(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinner2values[position]);
            adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            // set adapter
            ((Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2)).setAdapter(adapter2);
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // nothing selected, so set empty options
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(arg0.getContext(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, new String[0]);
            adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            ((Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2)).setAdapter(adapter2);
        }
    });


  }

}
```

logcat error

```
11-08 17:28:13.013: E/AndroidRuntime(1719): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-08 17:28:13.013: E/AndroidRuntime(1719): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.spinnersample/com.spinnersample.Spinner}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.spinnersample.Spinner
11-08 17:28:13.013: E/AndroidRuntime(1719):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1880)
11-08 17:28:13.013: E/AndroidRuntime(1719):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
11-08 17:28:13.013: E/AndroidRuntime(1719):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
11-08 17:28:13.013: E/AndroidRuntime(1719):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
11-08 17:28:13.013: E/AndroidRuntime(1719):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-08 17:28:13.013: E/AndroidRuntime(1719):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-08 17:28:13.013: E/AndroidRuntime(1719):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
11-08 17:28:13.013: E/AndroidRuntime(1719):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-08 17:28:13.013: E/AndroidRuntime(1719):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-08 17:28:13.013: E/AndroidRuntime(1719):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
11-08 17:28:13.013: E/AndroidRuntime(1719):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
11-08 17:28:13.013: E/AndroidRuntime(1719):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-08 17:28:13.013: E/AndroidRuntime(1719): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.spinnersample.Spinner
11-08 17:28:13.013: E/AndroidRuntime(1719):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
11-08 17:28:13.013: E/AndroidRuntime(1719):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
11-08 17:28:13.013: E/AndroidRuntime(1719):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
11-08 17:28:13.013: E/AndroidRuntime(1719):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)
11-08 17:28:13.013: E/AndroidRuntime(1719):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1871)
11-08 17:28:13.013: E/AndroidRuntime(1719):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: your log trace / printed stack trace uses to help you more... so post it below your code.

Comment: Have you declared this activity as LAUNCHER in manifest?

Comment: How are you importing `Spinner` ? It should be `import android.widget.Spinner`. It seems like it is using `com.spinnersample.Spinner`

Comment: Thank you All, problem was in manifest